# Is there some reliable encryption algorithm I can implement it by myself to encrypt some files in my computer?

Tags: encryption

I want to implement this algorithm by myself, using this to encrypt some files of repositories in my github. The algorithm does not need to be complicated, but reliable. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use an existing implementation?

Comment: Cause I want to add this program in my repository to the github, so that when I want to use this repository in another computer, I can just clone my repository and run the program to unencrypt, without finding the software or something else.

Comment: I think we're using the word "implement" in semantically different ways.  AES is the current "standard" encryption algorithm.  What language are you using?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I use C, C++ and Python.

Comment: Look at the examples in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).